# Scrape website that require login with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape website that requires login with Python and BeautifulSoup and requests libs. (no selenium)
This is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

auth = (username, password)
headers = {
    'authority': 'signon.springer.com',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'origin': 'https://signon.springer.com',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'referer': 'https://signon.springer.com/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fpress.nature.com%2Fcallback%3Fclient_name%3DCasClienthttps%3A%2F%2Fpress.nature.com&locale=en&gtm=GTM-WDRMH37&message=This+page+is+only+accessible+for+approved+journalists.+Please+log+into+your+press+site+account.+For+more+information%3A+https%3A%2F%2Fpress.nature.com%2Fapprove-as-a-journalist&_ga=2.25951165.1431685211.1610963078-2026442578.1607341887',
    'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    'cookie': 'SESSION=40d2be77-b3df-4eb6-9f3b-dac31ab66ce3',
}

params = (
    ('service', 'https://press.nature.com/callback?client_name=CasClienthttps://press.nature.com'),
    ('locale', 'en'),
    ('gtm', 'GTM-WDRMH37'),
    ('message', 'This page is only accessible for approved journalists. Please log into your press site account. For more information: https://press.nature.com/approve-as-a-journalist'),
    ('_ga', '2.25951165.1431685211.1610963078-2026442578.1607341887'),
)

data = {
  'username': username,
  'password': password,
  'rememberMe': 'true',
  'lt': 'LT-95560-qF7CZnAtuDqWS1sFQgBMqPVifS5mTg-16c07928-2faa-4ce0-58c7-5a1f',
  'execution': 'e1s1',
  '_eventId': 'submit',
  'submit': 'Login'
}

session = requests.session()
response = session.post('https://signon.springer.com/login', headers=headers, params=params, data=data, auth = auth)
print(response)
#time.sleep(5) does not make any diference
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup) # im not getting the results that I want
```

I'm not getting required HTML page with all data that I want, the HTML page that I'm getting is login page. This is the HTML response:
https://www.codepile.net/pile/EGY0YQMv

I think that the problem is because I want to scrape this page:

https://press.nature.com/press-releases

But when I click on that link (and Im not logged in) it redirects me to different website for loggin in:

https://signon.springer.com/login

For getting all `headers` and `params` and `data` values I have used:

```
inspect page -> network -> find login request -> copy cURL -> https://curl.trillworks.com/
```

I have tried multiple post and get methods, I have tried with and without `auth` param, but result is the same.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The value of `lt` within `data` is dynamic whereas you hardcoded it. Try scraping the value of `lt` using get requests and then use the `data` within post requests to see if that solves the issue.

Comment: can you show me how to do that?

Comment: I have added my HTML response to my question. So you can check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the script filling in your `username` and `password` fields and let me know what you get. If it still doesn't log you in, make sure to use additional headers within post requests.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://signon.springer.com/login'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36'
    res = s.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')   
    payload = {i['name']:i.get('value','') for i in soup.select('input[name]')}         
    #what the above line does is parse the keys and valuse available in the login form
    payload['username'] = username
    payload['password'] = password

    print(payload) #when you print this, you should see the required parameters within payload 

    s.post(link,data=payload)
    #as we have laready logged in, the login cookies are stored within the session
    #in our subsequesnt requests we are reusing the same session we have been using from the very beginning
    r = s.get('https://press.nature.com/press-releases')
    print(r.status_code)
    print(r.text)
```

Comment: Response is 200 *(like in my case), HTML response is: https://www.codepile.net/pile/QAPPz3Ar It says 'log in successful' but still, thats not the page that Im looking for. Thats not this page https://press.nature.com/press-releases

Comment: Try checking the html response now.

Comment: IT WORKS, THANKS ! Can you please write comments, so that I know what line is what>

Answer (score 0):

I think your auth parameter isn't in the correct format to be accepted by requests. You can try importing HTTPBasicAuth

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
auth = HTTPBasicAuth(username, password)
```

Comment: I have added my HTML response to my question. So you can check it

Comment: Sorry about that, it works for requests.post. With session you can use the tuple like this `with requests.Session() as s: s.auth = ('user', 'pass')`, but it also depends on your requirements if cookies need to be set, like in the accepted answer. The advanced usage page in the [docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/) has examples.